# construct_heap template class function

Tags: c++

I have a template function that takes in a vector and creates a heap

```
template<class T, class P> void construct_heap (vector <T>& v1, P pred)
 {
      make_heap(v1.begin(),v1.end());
      sort_heap(v1.begin(),v1.end(),pred);
 }
```

This works fine for ascending order . when i pass in construct_heap(v1, less());
it prints out the right data

but for descending order .. it doesn't work well.. i can't figure out why..

could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

also attaching a pic of the output ..

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: You might try passing your comparator predicate to [`std:make_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) as the third-parameter. Just saying...

Comment: You can avoid the call to `sort_heap` by passing `pred` to `merge_heap`. That leaves your question unanswered. But as @WhozCraig pointed out, you are perhaps passing a buggy `pred`. You could use `std::greater` and it will certainly work since you are dealing with integer numbers here.

Comment: but why pass the third argument in to the make_heap function there?.. so what is the point of sort_heap then ?

Comment: @psj01 the initial max_heap, based on the same comparator, has to be in place before `sort_heap` takes over. If you just `make_heap` that's all you get; a max-heap, and in your case the default comparator was `std::less<>` since you didn't specify one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicate used for making the initial max_heap should be the same as the predicate used during sorting. A general solution that works with all random-access containers below, demonstrated with both a vector and a deque.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <random>

template<class T, template<class,class...> class C, class P, class... Args>
void construct_heap(C<T,Args...>& v, const P& pred)
{
    std::make_heap(std::begin(v), std::end(v), pred); // <<== same predicate
    std::sort_heap(std::begin(v), std::end(v), pred);
}

template<class T, template<class, class...> class C, class... Args>
void print_seq(std::ostream& os, const C<T,Args...>& v)
{
    for (auto x : v)
        os << x << ' ';
    os << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 rng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1,99);

    std::vector<int> v1;
    v1.reserve(25);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v1), v1.capacity(),
                    [&](){ return dist(rng);});
    print_seq(std::cout, v1);

    std::deque<int> d1(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    print_seq(std::cout, d1);

    construct_heap(v1, std::greater<int>());
    print_seq(std::cout, v1);

    construct_heap(d1, std::greater<int>());
    print_seq(std::cout, d1);

    return 0;

}
```

**Output** (obviously varies)

```
16 6 52 81 7 95 72 76 40 68 9 77 66 73 44 7 64 44 3 58 89 24 51 43 26 
16 6 52 81 7 95 72 76 40 68 9 77 66 73 44 7 64 44 3 58 89 24 51 43 26 
95 89 81 77 76 73 72 68 66 64 58 52 51 44 44 43 40 26 24 16 9 7 7 6 3 
95 89 81 77 76 73 72 68 66 64 58 52 51 44 44 43 40 26 24 16 9 7 7 6 3
```

Comment: "The predicate used for making the initial max_heap should be the same as the predict used during sorting. " - THANKS!!